# Visual Studio wants Ninja Generator even though I don't have it installed

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, ninja

I am trying to set up a simple project so I can learn some OpenGL. Here is my CmakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("opengl_1")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules/")

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if (OpenGL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)
if (GLFW_FOUND)
    include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC "src/*")
file(GLOB_RECURSE INCLUDES "include/*")

include_directories("include")

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (opengl1 ${SRC} ${INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(opengl1 ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
```

I had abandoned Visual Studio Code for Visual Studio 2017 due the problem generating the compile commands file on Windows. It required Ninja generator and I had a ton of trouble getting cmake to use it.

So now, I `cd` in my project directory and do `cmake .`:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.14.26431.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.14.26431.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenGL: opengl32
-- Found GLFW: C:/libraries/glfw/include (found version "3.2.1")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ...
```

No mention of Ninja generator anywhere. However, when I open the solution in VS2017 and go to update intellisense with "generate" I get:

```
1> Does not match the generator used previously: Visual Studio 15 2017
1> Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.
CMake Error: Error: generator : Ninja
Does not match the generator used previously: Visual Studio 15 2017
Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.
```

When I remove these things the error still occurs.

What is going on here? If I require Ninja anyway can someone tell me what I need to do?

Thank you!

Comment: When use "generate", set the proper [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generators.7.html). Do not use Ninja generator if you don't have it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev If I install Ninja, can I use it with MSVC?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 is shipped with `ninja`. On my PC [tag:ninja] can be found under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja` folder. In case of the above error: you should always start for a fresh binary output directory if you switch the CMake generator.

Answer (score 2):

So I will answer my own question because this took a weird bunch of things to be happening at once to get this error to occur.

1. I had initially installed Ninja, and then uninstalled it prior to this error occurring.
2. I had originally made the Cmake file through VS' `Cmake Project` option, I suspect this used Ninja in the background
3. I uninstalled Ninja

As a result of (3) the code completion no longer worked as expected. To remedy this situation:

1. Delete all unnecessary Cmake files
2. Open a VS developer command prompt
3. Run `cmake .`

This SHOULD default to the normal MSBUILD routine and fix the problem. Somehow `cmake -G Ninja .` was getting run in the background *even* when I generated the build files from a non-VS command prompt. It took the VS command prompt to fix it.

Hopefully this helps someone. This confused me.